# Relating values using lists in Laravel 4, how do i do this?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

My database structure is like this:

```
User
-id
-jobRole (comma separated list of option ids)

Options
-id (included in the list of ids in jobRole above)
-value
```

To relate 'jobRole' in the user table to the options table I would have done something like this:

```
jobRoles = SELECT * FROM Options WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4,5)
```

When I setup the relation ship in laravel as 'belongsTo', the Query it runs is this:

```
SELECT * FROM Options WHERE id IN('1,2,3,4,5')
```

*See how it quotes the list!

How can I have laravel run this same query WITHOUT the quotes?

Currently in my model I have the relationship structured like this:

```
public function jobRole(){
    return $this->belongsTo('JobRole', 'jobRole');
}
```

Comment: **Never, ever** store delimited string values in a database. Normalize your data by creating a many-to-many table instead. That way you'll be able to normally query your data.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will do that in the future. However, is there a solution to this as I can't change my data around to accommodate?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with 'peterm'. But here is your answer:

`$Options = Options::whereIn('id', explode(',', $User->jobRole))->get();`

see http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects